# How to keep changes made on another sheet based on conditional formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have 2 sheets, worksheet A where the changes are made using drop downs and sheet B (a matrix or a library) that gets updated based on a conditional formatting.

Sheet A

2 columns with staff names assigned for training based on different types of operations in rows using drop downs. Once training is complete, trainer acknowledges training complete by selecting "Y" using drop down.

[image: Image of Sheet A]

Sheet B

This is a training Matrix where every staff's training from sheet A gets recorded in sheet B with check marks. Each cell in sheet B has a conditional code.

Example: `(=IF(OR(AND(SheetA!I7=CodeSheet!$AG$7,SheetA!H7="Y"),AND(SheetA!L7=CodeSheet!$AG$7,SheetA!K7="Y")),'Drop-Down'!$J$5,""))`

After a selected staff completes their training in sheet A, the trainer selects "Y" from drop down in Sheet A to confirm completion of training and that updates Sheet B matrix with a check mark.

[image: Image of Sheet B]

Problem:

Once a staff's training is complete, another staff will be selected to train for the same operation using the drop downs feature. But when I do this, the check mark for the previous staff (who completed their training) in Matrix Sheet B  disappears. How can I make the changes in Matrix Sheet B permanent?

What are my options? I'm building this Excel tool to help organize the training schedule and tracking at work more efficient.

Comment: Please update the image and show the full row and column names

Comment: What does your question have to do with Python?

Comment: @TheGridLock Just updated the images as requested

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-vba solution, Here are the steps that I took:

- Be sure to turn off **[Iterative feature](https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/excel-iterative-calculation/)** [File/Option/Formulas: uncheck Enable iterative]
- fill the formula in all the necessary cells.
- now, the formula values display = 0, use conditional formating to [Hide zero](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/pro-tip-three-ways-to-hide-zero-values-in-an-excel-sheet/)
- check enable Iterative and set up with the **maximum iterations = 1** for each following formula
- With each corresponding value in E4, each cell I4, J4, K4 will operate only once

This is an animation that describes how it works

```
E4=IF(AND(E4=0,$A$4="E"),$A$1,E4)
F4=IF(AND(F4=0,$A$4="F"),$A$1,F4)
G4=IF(AND(G4=0,$A$4="G"),$A$1,G4)
```

[image]

Your formula would be something like

```
E4=IF(AND(E4=0,OR(AND(SheetA!I7=CodeSheet!$AG$7,SheetA!H7="Y"),AND(SheetA!L7=CodeSheet!$AG$7,SheetA!K7="Y")),'Drop-Down'!$J$5,E4)
```

Comment: ...Thank you for the formula. It works really well. Your help is much appreciated!